# Sum of combinations of numbers

Tags: math, numbers, combinations, discrete-mathematics

I want to solve a mathematical problem in a fastest possible way.
I have a set of natural numbers between 1 to n, for example {1,2,3,4,n=5} and I want to calculate a formula like this:

s = 1*2*3*4+1*2*3*5+1*2*4*5+1*3*4*5+2*3*4*5

as you can see, each element in the sum is a multiplications of n-1 numbers in the set. For example in (1*2*3*4), 5 is excluded and in (1*2*3*5), 4 is excluded. I know some of the multiplications are repeated, for example (1*2) is repeated in 3 of the multiplications. How can I solve this problem with least number of multiplications.

Sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Comment: How is this a programming problem? What have you tried? And are divisions to be counted as a multiplication or in some other way? (I can think of several methods that use one or more divisions or reciprocals.) And what about additions? Every multiplication could be replaced by multiple additions so that no multiplications are used.

Comment: I don't want to use division. Only multiplications and sums. This is one part of a bigger problem that I want to solve. I tried structuring numbers in a tree but I couldn't find a good structure that can be able to use repeated multiplications.

Comment: You haven't answered about replacing all multiplications with additions. Also, is your goal to minimize time (as you say in your first sentence) or multiplications (as you say in your almost-last sentence) or something else?

Comment: I want to run a code that solves this in a computer. So I want to reduce multiplications and use number of sums, but I don't think that replacing all multiplications with sums is a faster way. Because I think this way we need more CPU cycles to solve it.

Comment: I really want to do that but I need 15 or more reputations that I don't have. Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: Actually I did that. I think it is recorded but not shown. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that does not "cheat" by replacing multiplication with repeated addition or by using division. The idea is to replace your expression with

1*2*3*4 + 5*(1*2*3 + 4*(1*2 + 3*(1 + 2)))

This used 9 multiplications for the numbers 1 through 5. In general I think the multiplication count would be one less than the (n-1)th triangular number, n * (n - 1) / 2 - 1. Here is Python code that stores intermediate factorial values to reduce the number of multiplications to just 6, or in general 2 * n - 4, and the addition count to the same (but half of them are just adding 1):

```
def f(n):
    fact = 1
    term = 2
    sum = 3
    for j in range(2, n):
        fact *= j
        term = (j + 1) * sum
        sum = fact + term
    return sum
```

The only way to find which algorithm is the fastest is to code all of them in one language, and run each using a timer.

Answer (score 0):

The following would be the most straightforward answer.

```
def f(n):
    result = 0
    nList = [i+1 for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(len(nList)):
        result += reduce(lambda x, y: x*y,(nList[:i]+nList[i+1:]))
return result
```

Walkthrough - use the reduce function to multiply all list's of length n-1 and add to the variable result.

Comment: I know this way, but is there a way that I can use replicated multiplications to solve it faster?

Comment: @Bazinevis do you mean recursion?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to minimise the number of multiplications, you can replace all the multiplications by additions, like this:

```
// Compute 1*2*…*n
mult_all(n):
    if n = 1
        return 1
    res = 0
    // by adding 1*2*…*(n-1) an entirety of n times
    for i = 1 to n do
        res += mult_all(n-1)
    return res

// Compute sum of 1*2*…*(i-1)*(i+1)*…*n
sum_of_mult_all_but_one(n):
    if n = 1
        return 0
    // by computing 1*2*…*(n-1) + (sum 1*2*…*(i-1)*(i+1)*…*(n-1))*n
    res = mult_all(n-1)
    for i = 1 to n do
        res += sum_of_mult_all_but_one(n-1)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that would work with javascript. It is not the fastest way because it is not optimized, but it should work if you want to just find the answer.

```
function combo(n){
var mult = 1;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    mult = 1;
    for (var j = 1; j<= n; j++){
        if(j != i){
            mult = mult*j;
        }
    }
    sum += mult;
}
return (sum);
}

alert(combo(n));
```

Comment: You're right. Thank you for pointing this out. I will change it.